# Transactional Email Change Logo not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I'm trying to change the logo of the transaction email. But upon changing of logo it's not displaying the preview of the uploaded image. So now I tried to preview using the inspector and below is what I got

[image]

So if I click the preview tab this is what it looks like. Based from the request params it's an AJAX so I'm expecting it to be in JSON format but it's returning an HTML format as shown below
[image]

I was expecting a preview of the uploaded image to be displayed but I can't see anything. I already made all folders 777 (I know it's not safe but just want to make it work for now).

Any solution or fix with this? BTW I'm using a vagrant box although I know this is not the issue. I checked the logs both the server and application logs but there are no error.